# Filestream - The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: c#, unicode

I have this C# code which is supposed to open a file.

```
string filePath = @"‪C:\Data\123.jpg";
FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath);
```

But, it breaks at second line with error message `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

The exception details also shows `C:\\dotnet\\solution\\projectname\\‪C:\\Data\\123.jpg'` . Why it goes to the project path?

Comment: Are you sure from the path `C:\Data\123.jpg`??

Comment: Yes. I am sure the file is there.

Comment: Careful copy/pasting strings, you might get more than you bargained for.  The first letter of that string is not 'C'.  Diagnose by putting filePath.ToCharArray() in the debug expression, now you can see the invisible U+202A codepoint.  Simply retype to fix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now that's a tricky one, yet so simple.

The code above is correct, it's more or less like the example in the Microsoft documentation.

But there is an invisible Unicode character [E280AA](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128)

> U+202A ‪   e2 80 aa    LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING

just before the letter "C".

Therefore this doesn't work:

```
string filePath = @"‪C:\Data\123.jpg";
```

But this one does:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Data\123.jpg";
```

The first one (just the actual string) as hex code looks like this:

22**E280AA**433A5C446174615C3132332E6A706722

the second one doesn't have the bold sequence.
You can see this in the debugger or with the help of tools like
Notepad++ where you can use Extensions/Converter/ASCII->HEX to see the hex code.

Comment: I had this probleme when I copied and paste the path into the debug parameter in visual studio. Sound like I had an hidden char